# Solving $\frac{L-E}{(I-L)^\alpha} = AN^{-a}+BD^{-b}$ for $L$

Tags: closed-form

I want to show how to solve for $L$ in the following equation:

$$
\frac{L-E}{(I-L)^\alpha} = AN^{-a}+BD^{-b}
$$

where $a,b,N,D>0$.

I think that this has no closed solution, but I want to make sure I am not overlooking anything. If this does not have a close solution, can I somehow approximate the solution in closed form?

Comment: It does potentially have closed solutions in some cases ($\alpha=1, 2, \frac{1}{2}$ , ...) but not for most $\alpha$ values. Any approximation procedure for $L$ will very much depend on the coefficients and their relative magnitudes..

Comment: @Jsevillamol There is a hypergeometric [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FindRoot%5B-x%2B1.4%2B0.2+%281-x%29%5E3.2%2C%7Bx%2C1%7D%5D) if one evaluates [this series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+lim%5B1.4%2Bsum%5B0.2%5En%2Fn%21+D%5B%281-x%29%5E%283.2+n%29%2C%7Bx%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C9%7D%5D%2Cx-%3E1.4%5D). Are you looking for all complex solutions?

Comment: @Jsevillamol What is known about $A$ and $\alpha$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{L-E}{(I-L)^\alpha}=c$$

We see, for rational $\alpha$, your equation is related to a polynomial equation and we can use the solution theory of polynomial equations.

But for non-rational $\alpha$, your equation is related to a polynomial equation in dependence of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($L,(I-L)^\alpha$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $L$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

$$\frac{L-E}{(I-L)^\alpha}=c$$
$$L-E=c\ (I-L)^\alpha$$
$$L-E-c\ (I-L)^\alpha=0$$
$L\to I-x^\frac{1}{\alpha}$:
for real $\alpha,x$:
$$I-x^\frac{1}{\alpha}-E-cx=0$$
$$cx+x^\frac{1}{\alpha}+(E-I)=0$$

We see, this equation is a trinomial equation with real exponents. We can transform it to a form like in equation 8.1 of [Belkic 2019]. Solutions in terms of Bell polynomials, Pochhammer symbols or confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ can be obtained therefore.

[[Belkić 2019] Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)

[[Szabó 2010] Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\alpha$ for easier MathJax and apply [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem): $$\frac{L-E}{(I-L)^a}=b\implies L=1-e^\frac{2\pi i k}a\left(\frac{L-E}b\right)^\frac1a=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^\frac{2\pi i k n}a}{(-\sqrt[a]b)^nn!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}(z-E)^\frac1a\right|_1$$ Therefore: $$L_k=E+(1-E)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac na\right)!}{\left(\left(\frac1a-1\right)n+1\right)!n!}\left(-\frac{(1-E)^{\frac1a-1}}{\sqrt[a]b}e^\frac{2\pi ik}a\right)^n $$ [shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2B%281-2.3%29+sum%5B%CE%93%281+%2B+n%2F5.2%29%2F%CE%93%282%2B+%281%2F5.2-1%29+n%29+%28-1%2F0.8%5E%281%2F5.2%29+%281+-+2.3%29%5E%281%2F5.2-1%29+exp%282*%7B-3%2C-2%2C-1%2C0%2C1%2C2%2C3%7D+%CF%80+i%2F5.2%29%29%5En%2Fn%21%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=complex+solutions+%28z-2.3%29%2F%281-z%29%5E5.2%3D0.8). So the [Fox Wright function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function), a special case of [Fox H](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoxH.html), appears:

$$\bbox[3px,border: 4px ridge cyan]{\frac{L-E}{(1-L)^a}=b\implies L_k=E+(1-E)\,_1\Psi_1\left(^{\ \,\left(1,\frac1a\right)}_{\left(2,\frac1a-1\right)};-\frac{(1-E)^{\frac1a-1}}{\sqrt[a]b}e^\frac{2\pi ik}a\right)}$$